# R: Computing mean rows depending on date. tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, mean

Some of you help with this question through base R but I am trying to do it now with tidy data. Here is my dataset:

```
data <- tibble( "DATE_FIRE"= c("1989-07-31", "1989-07-31", "1989-07-31", "1989-07-31","1989-07-31","1989-08-31", "1989-08-31", "1989-08-31", "1989-08-31","1989-08-31"), 
       "FID_FIRE" = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
       "date" = c("1988-01-01", "1989-01-01","1990-01-01","1991-06-07","1992-01-01", "1988-01-01", "1989-01-01","1990-01-01","1991-06-07","1992-01-01"),
       "NDVI" = c( 0.9, 0.8, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.85, 0.15, 0.30, 0.50))
> data
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   DATE_FIRE  FID_FIRE date        NDVI
   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
 1 1989-07-31        1 1988-01-01  0.9 
 2 1989-07-31        1 1989-01-01  0.8 
 3 1989-07-31        1 1990-01-01  0.1 
 4 1989-07-31        1 1991-06-07  0.2 
 5 1989-07-31        1 1992-01-01  0.3 
 6 1989-08-31        2 1988-01-01  0.8 
 7 198`enter code here`9-08-31        2 1989-01-01  0.85
 8 1989-08-31        2 1990-01-01  0.15
 9 1989-08-31        2 1991-06-07  0.3 
10 1989-08-31        2 1992-01-01  0.5
```

As you see I have dates of 2 forest plots , fire 1 and fire 2 (`FID_FIRE` column). `DATE_FIRE` tells us when the fire in each plot took place I also have data in terms of `NDVI` (greenness parameters) for these plots, before and after the fire (see columns `date` and `NDVI`).

I would like to add a column computing for each plot the **mean value** of `NDVI` **before** the fire took place. In case of `FID_FIRE=1` it would be the mean of `NDVI` values of `row 1` and `2`.

The output should look like:

```
> desired_output
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   DATE_FIRE  FID_FIRE date        NDVI meanPrefire
   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 1989-07-31        1 1988-01-01  0.9        0.85 
 2 1989-07-31        1 1989-01-01  0.8        0.85 
 3 1989-07-31        1 1990-01-01  0.1        0.85 
 4 1989-07-31        1 1991-06-07  0.2        0.85 
 5 1989-07-31        1 1992-01-01  0.3        0.85 
 6 1989-08-31        2 1988-01-01  0.8        0.825
 7 1989-08-31        2 1989-01-01  0.85       0.825
 8 1989-08-31        2 1990-01-01  0.15       0.825
 9 1989-08-31        2 1991-06-07  0.3        0.825
10 1989-08-31        2 1992-01-01  0.5        0.825
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(FID_FIRE) %>%
  mutate(meanPrefire = mean(NDVI[date < DATE_FIRE], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   FID_FIRE [2]
   DATE_FIRE  FID_FIRE date        NDVI meanPrefire
   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 1989-07-31        1 1988-01-01  0.9        0.85 
 2 1989-07-31        1 1989-01-01  0.8        0.85 
 3 1989-07-31        1 1990-01-01  0.1        0.85 
 4 1989-07-31        1 1991-06-07  0.2        0.85 
 5 1989-07-31        1 1992-01-01  0.3        0.85 
 6 1989-08-31        2 1988-01-01  0.8        0.825
 7 1989-08-31        2 1989-01-01  0.85       0.825
 8 1989-08-31        2 1990-01-01  0.15       0.825
 9 1989-08-31        2 1991-06-07  0.3        0.825
10 1989-08-31        2 1992-01-01  0.5        0.825
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, meanPrefire := mean(NDVI[date < DATE_FIRE], na.rm = TRUE), .(FID_FIRE)]
```